# Iterating over a query builder instance, removing some items then returning the instance modified

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query I am building for a server-side searching/filtering functionality, I have a query builder instance which is changed every time the user checks a new filter, it was all going well until I had a filter that checks for a ManyToMany relationship.

First of all here's the code in my controller:

```
public function index()
    {

        $hotels = (new Hotel)->newQuery();

        if (request()->has('category_id')) {
            $hotels->whereIn('category_id', request()->category_id);
        }


        if(request()->has('location_id')) {
            $hotels->whereIn('location_id', request()->location_id);
        }

        if(request()->has('facility_id')) {
            $filtered = $hotels->get()->filter(function ($hotel) {
                return $hotel->facilities()->whereIn('facility_id', [4])->get()->isNotEmpty();
            });

           // dd($filtered);
        }

        request()->flash();

        if(count(request()->all())) {
            $hotels = $hotels->paginate(2)->appends([
                'category_id' => request('category_id'),
                'location_id' => request('location_id'),
            ]);
        }

        if(! count(request()->all())) {
            $hotels = Hotel::inRandomOrder()->paginate(8);
        }

        return view('hotels', compact('hotels'));
    }
```

And here's the problem, let's say i have 20 records, I need to directly modify and remove from `$hotels` any empty collection (a **hotel**) that doesn't match the filter() method, but what happens is that the `$hotels` variable stays the same with all 20 records, I have to instead use a new variable i.e `$filtered` to get the modified results off of the `filtered()` method, but in that case I can't keep building on the `$hotels` instance, and if let's say I changed the end code to support the new `$filtered` variable, if there are no `facilities` in the request, my code will just break.

In summary here's what I need, I need to iterate over the `$hotels` variable, remove some items, and then return that `$hotels` as a query builder to keep building on it.

*Here's what I tried*:

- I tried the reduce method, it worked almost like `filter()`, I had to use a new variable to get the results, but `filter()` was better.
- Let's say that 'facilities' is the last query I'll call before returning, I tried to reassign $hotels to $filtered like `$hotels = $filtered` because I won't need the query builder anymore right?, but at the bottom of the code I am paginating the results, and that doesn't work, it told me that the method `paginate()` doesn't exist on the collection I think.

Comment: use `whereHas()` to filter facilities

Comment: Could you write an answer to be more clear/specific?

Comment: share your `Hotel` model class and its `relation` function with `facilities`

Comment: Thank you the question was already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
if(request()->has('facility_id')) {
    $hotels->whereHas('facilities', function ($query) {
        return $query->whereIn('facility_id', [4])->where('facility_id', '<>', '');
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer works without the 'isNotEmpty()' at the end, that gives an error because it doesn't exist on a query builder, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should  use below when (efficient way ) conditional clauses

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses

Example

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->when(request()->category_id, function ($query, request()->category_id) {
                    return $query->where('category_id', request()->category_id);
                })->get();
```